# Use SVG image inline inside CSS :before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I have a simple SVG image:

```
<svg width="auto" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 80 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path d="M0 0 H 20 L 10 20 Z" fill="yellow"></path>
    <path d="M30 20 H 50 L 40 0 Z" fill="black"></path>
    <path d="M60 0 H 80 L 70 20 Z" fill="yellow"></path>
</svg>
```

Instead of including it as an image, I thought to include it inline into a ::before pseudo-element with SASS:

```
div:before {
  content: str-replace(url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg width='auto' height='10px' viewBox='0 0 80 20' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0 H 20 L 10 20 Z' fill='yellow'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M30 20 H 50 L 40 0 Z' fill='black'%3E%3C/path%3E%3Cpath d='M60 0 H 80 L 70 20 Z' fill='yellow'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E'), "#", "%23");
}
```

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/zRMmpr

However, I get an error message both in Codepen and my local compiler. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
div::before {
 content: '';
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22auto%22%20height%3D%2210%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2080%2020%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%200h20L10%2020z%22%20fill%3D%22%23ff0%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M30%2020h20L40%200z%22/%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M60%200h20L70%2020z%22%20fill%3D%22%23ff0%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

I use http://www.grumpicon.com/ this website to convert SVGs for CSS background

Comment: Yes! I was looking for a tool like this but failed!

Comment: @sdvnksv I use https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to optimize the SVG and make it smaller and then run it in grumpicon to create that link.